# Selecting a certificate authority for https

Tags: https

How do I select a certificate authority in order to use https rather than http?

What criteria should I have in mind when looking?

It seems that there are both paid (like year plans) and free alternatives. What's the difference?

FYI I am hosting most of the content of my domain on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no technological difference between a free SSL certificate from organizations like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and a paid DV (domain validated) certificate. There's also no meaningful difference between the $7 DV certificate Namecheap offers and the $149 DV certificate GeoTrust offers.

EV (extended validation) certificates always cost money, and are generally not necessary unless you're PayPal or a bank or something. (Even Amazon.com can't be bothered to set one up)

Comment: A note: the only reason I'd caution on Let's Encrypt is you have to renew the certificate every three months rather than annually. They make it supremely easy, though.

Comment: Thanks, Wikipedia just directed me to let's encrypt so I'm looking at that now. In a sense doing something every three months could actually be helpful to me since I tend to forget how to do something if I don't do it often enough. Maybe they should make it monthly. :-)

Comment: @Jonny You can do it five times a week, if you like. https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/public-beta-rate-limits/4772/2 My experience with Let's Encrypt has been very good thus far, it's very user friendly as SSL goes.

Comment: I just threw Let's Encrypt in the crontab for once a month. So far so good.

Comment: As I'm on GAE there seems to be some suggestions on automating most of this. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12535 So at this point, I'm just gonna leave this subject for now, make the Internets fix these things for me. Back to coding games...

Comment: @Jonny I'm an AWS guy so I'm really hoping Amazon goes and puts Let's Encrypt support into their load balancer offerings. :-)